# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after two splits

Tags: java

I want to split a string three times.

This is the string:
`21.06.2016;00:30`

My function looks like this:

```
String[] split = dateV.split(";");
String[] date = split[0].split(".");
String[] time = split[1].split(":");
```

date[0] should contain "21" after all

So the first part works great.

My two strings are

```
split[0] = 21.06.2016
split[1] = 00:30
```

But when I call `split[0].split(".");` I get a

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0`

Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.split` uses regular expressions to do the split, and a dot is a special character when regular expressions are used.

To split using a dot, you need to escape it like this

```
String[] date = split[0].split("\\.");
```

Comment: Better to use ''Pattern.quote'